# How to proof that convergence on metric hold iff convergence on measure

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that fact. 
Let $\mu X < \infty$ Then $d(f_n,f) \to 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f_n \to f$ in measure. When $d(f,g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+ |f-g|}d\mu$

I know that if $f_n \to f$ hold iff $\mu \{|f_n-f| \ge \varepsilon\} \to 0 \ \ \forall \varepsilon > 0$. But how to deduce that $d(f_n,f) \to 0$ Do I use a Chebyshev's_inequality?

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

"$\Leftarrow$":

$$\begin{align*} d(f_n,f) &= \int_{|f_n-f| < \varepsilon} \underbrace{\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}}_{\leq \varepsilon} \, d\mu + \int_{|f_n-f| \geq \varepsilon} \underbrace{\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}}_{\leq 1} \, d\mu\end{align*}$$

"$\Rightarrow$": Note that $[0,\infty) \ni x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing. Therefore, $$\begin{align*} d(f_n,f) &\geq \int_{|f_n-f| \geq \varepsilon} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} \, d\mu \geq \int_{|f_n-f| \geq \varepsilon} \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} \, d\mu \\ &= \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} \cdot \mu(|f_n-f| \geq \varepsilon) \end{align*}$$